# Python error in serverless framework stating - Serverless Error: spawn docker ENOENT

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Error:

```
Running "serverless" from node_modules

Deploying serverless-flask to stage dev (us-east-1)

✖ Stack serverless-flask-dev failed to deploy (0s)
Environment: darwin, node 16.0.0, framework 3.1.1 (local) 3.1.1v (global), plugin 6.0.0, SDK 4.3.1
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Error: spawn docker ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I'm following these instructions (https://www.serverless.com/blog/flask-python-rest-api-serverless-lambda-dynamodb/) and can't seem to figure this out since the base app is in python and not javascript... most people who have solved this solved it using javascript.

Comment: Are you using `serverless-python-requirements` plugin ?

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to post the instructions i was following @TheSmartMonkey here they are - https://www.serverless.com/blog/flask-python-rest-api-serverless-lambda-dynamodb/

Comment: If you are on 64-bit linux system , then  there's not a great reason to actually use docker so you need to update the `serverless.yml` file with following changes:-
 `dockerizePip: "false"` or just remove the entry from `serverless.yml` file. In my case it was set to  `dockerizePip: non-linux` .I just removed the entry and everything works fine!!

Answer (score 6):

To solve this issue you need to update your **serverless.yml** file with these changes in the custom block

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
  pythonBin: python3
  dockerizePip: "false"
```

I also face the same issue my issue was with **dockerizePip** it was set to

```
dockerizePip: non-linux
```

either remove this entry from **serverless.yml** file or just set it to false

Comment: Does serverless need nodejs and python3 in the same container in this case?

Comment: No, we need either python or Nodejs @KenJ not both

Answer (score 5):

To be able to deploy your project with `serverless-python-requirements` you need to have docker on your machine (if you are on windows consider using docker desktop or a linux vm)

Why do I need Docker ?

When you do a `sls deploy`, `serverless-python-requirements` launch a docker container to install all the dependencies you've put in your `requirements.txt` file that will be used during the deployement process

You are getting this error because your container is not launch correctly

Comment: thanks, i installed docker and it worked like a charm in the deploy build process however I am now getting this error:

Error:
The security token included in the request is invalid.

I'm not sure what security token they are talking about and where i would place it. Is that something i generate from docker?

Comment: maybe related to aws verify your `.aws/credentials` file AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are correct